# Comparing and counting string correlations with Haskell

Tags: haskell, comparison, classification, string-comparison

I'm working on a pretty complicated (complicated for me, at least) function that I'd like to use to count the number of times a word in a list corresponds with a word in a database.

An example using random words:

```
let input = [("InputName", ["dog", "cat", "cat"...]), ...]
let database = ["dog", "cat", "badger"...]
```

After several hours of mental gymnastics, I came up with this hideous function that almost works. I've simplified it so it'll make sense in the context of this example:

```
findMatches input database = [ (snd x, wordCount (snd x)) | x <- input ]
    where
        wordCount ys = sum[ if y `elem` database then 1 else 0 | y <- ys ]
```

My goal, my hope, my wish would be to have an output that reads:

```
[("dog", 1), ("cat", 2), ("badger", 0)]
```

Any suggestions or nudges in the right direction would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I finally made a function that works. catWordCount counts the number of times a database entry appears in an input. I'm working on a better implementation using fold.

```
let input = words "5 4 10 0 1 9 1"
let database = [("C1", words "1 2 3 4 5"), ("C2", words "6 7 8 9 10")]

catwordCount input database

catWordCount fs zs = [ (fst f, inputSearch (snd f)) | f <- fs ]
    where
        inputSearch gs = [ (g, wordCount [g]) | g <- gs ]
        wordCount hs = sum[ if h == z then 1 else 0 | h <- hs, z <- zs ]
```

And the output:

```
(["C1", [("1",2),("2",0),("3",0),("4",1),("5",1)])
(["C2", [("6",0),("7",0),("8",0),("9",1),("10",1)])
```

Comment: I just found my oversight. I blame lack of sleep. Working on a better implementation now.

Comment: for nontrivial app, look at haskell fulltext indexing code eg Holumbus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep a `Map` of counts that you update for each item. Since you don't want to include items from the input list that are not in the database, if I understood correctly,

```
alter :: Ord k => (Maybe a -> Maybe a) -> k -> Map k a -> Map k a
```

is a good way to do that. The supplied key `k` is looked up, and if it's present, the argument to the update function will we `Just value`, otherwise it will be `Nothing`. If the result of the update function is `Nothing`, the key will be deleted from the `Map` (or not added, if it wasn't present), if the result is `Just something`, the key will be associated with `something` in the altered `Map`.

So you start with a `Map` mapping every item to 0,

```
m0 :: Map String Int
m0 = fromList $ zip database (repeat 0)
```

to update, you want to increment the count if the item is in `database`, and not change anything otherwise,

```
incr :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
incr (Just n) = Just (n+1)
incr Nothing  = Nothing
```

or, shorter, `incr = fmap (+1)` using the `Functor` instance of `Maybe`.

Then the resulting map is simply

```
finalMap :: Map String Int
finalMap = foldl (flip $ alter incr) m0 $ snd input
```

and if you want a list rather than a `Map`, just call `assocs` or `toList` on `finalMap`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and help, Daniel. I'm looking up the functions and suggestions you've listed.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be exactly what you are looking for, but try this:

```
import Data.List

countMatches :: [(String, [String])] -> [(String, Int)]
countMatches = map (\l -> (head l, length l)) . group . sort . concat . map snd
```

Hopefully the function compositions are not too confusing. I'll go over it step by step. Say you run this function with input

```
[("", ["a", "b"]), ("", ["b", "c", "x", "a"]), ("", ["y", "b", "z"])]
```

After `map snd` it is

```
[["a", "b"], ["b", "c", "x", "a"], ["y", "b", "z"]]
```

After `concat`,

```
["a", "b", "b", "c", "x", "a", "y", "b", "z"]
```

After `sort`,

```
["a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "x", "y", "z"]
```

After `group`,

```
[["a", "a"], ["b", "b", "b"], ["c"], ["x"], ["y"], ["z"]]
```

And finally `map (\l -> (head l, length l))` produces

```
[("a", 2), ("b", 3), ("c", 1), ("x", 1), ("y", 1), ("z", 1)]
```

Comment: Thank you, Karolis. I'm researching your suggestions now.